# Spring rest template close connection if the data is more

Tags: spring, http, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I have a scenario where the http connection needs to be closed if the server is sending more data than expected. i.e after a few seconds of receiving the data, I would like the close the connection automatically. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a timeout on your RestTemplate. That way you can terminate any long running requests.

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) 
    {
        return restTemplateBuilder
           .setConnectTimeout(...)
           .setReadTimeout(...)
           .build();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this, still not working - RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).build();